# can we change type from part to lvm in linux

Tags: linux, filesystems, disk

in lsblk command, we can see type of disk like part or lvm.
I wanted to change from part to lvm without loosing any data, is it possible?

```
[root@xxboot]# lsblk
NAME                  MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
fd0                     2:0    1    4K  0 disk
sda                     8:0    0   32G  0 disk
├─sda1                  8:1    0  500M  0 part /boot
└─sda2                  8:2    0 31.5G  0 part /
sdb                     8:16   0   16G  0 disk
└─sdb1                  8:17   0   16G  0 part /mnt/resource
sdc                     8:32   0   32G  0 disk
└─vgnewApp-lvnewApp   253:1    0   32G  0 lvm  /appnew
sdf                     8:80   0   10G  0 disk
└─sdf1                  8:81   0   10G  0 part /test1
```

Comment: You can't just change the partition type. You need to create a physical volume on the partition (the command is `pvcreate`), which will destroy the filesystem header on it. You will then have to add that physical volume to a volume group and create a logical volume in that volume group. This is desctructive, but of course you can back up your data and restore it to the logical volume. Which disks do you want to turn into logical volumes, and why?

Comment: I was trying for sdf but yes data is getting wiped out while creating pv on partition.

Comment: To be precise, `pvcreate` and `vgcreate` only write a short header near the beginning of the disk. This does not really wipe out the data, but it makes it hard to find it. Recovery is possible, but you can't have an LVM header **and** the original filesystem. Either one or the other.